# Логика DirectShow при работе с веб - камерой

Tags: c++, winapi, web-camera, directshow

Думаю освоить DirectShow, так как помимо вебки далее придётся работать со звуком, а DS, как я понял, универсальное и актуальное на данный момент средство для работы с мультимедиа в Windows. Хочу начать с того, чтобы переписать свой класс камеры на DirectShow, но мне что-то не ясна логика работы этого API - графы, фильтры, инерфейсы...

Объясните пожалуйста пошагово, как при помощи DirectShow получить кадр с камеры?

Например, с vfw32 я делал следующее:
1. Создаю окно захвата `capCreateCaptureWindow`
2. Перебираю девайсы от 0 до 9, пытаясь `capGetDriverDescription`
3. Если успешно по пункту два, делаю бинд драйвера на окно захвата `capDriverConnect`
4. Если третий успешно, настраиваю камеру (`capGetVideoFormat` и `capSetVideoFormat`) и устанавливаю коллбек процедуру (`capSetCallbackOnFrame`), в которой и описано заполнение глобального RGB-буфера кадра из структуры `LPVIDEOHDR`.
То есть после этих действий, я отправляю окну захвата `WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME` и получаю `unsigned char *` буфер с RGB-палитрой кадра.
**Как прийти к этому RGB-буферу при помощи DirectShow?**

Answer (score 2):

Логика DirectShow состоит в том, что управляющий код строит цепочку фильтров и изменяет состояние всей цепочки (начинает и останавливает веб-камеру, в частности), но при этом не имеет прямого доступа к данным. Фильтры, участвующие в цепочке, обмениваются данными между собой.

Поэтому если проводить аналогию с указанными шагами, то возникает ряд проблем:

1. У управляющего приложения нет доступа к буферам кадров
2. Не обязательно вообще RGB буферы существуют, т.к. по-большому счету ни для видеозахвата, ни для отображения, ни для записи RGB буферы не являются обязательными (а даже в большинстве случаев даже в той или иной мере "вредны")

В рамках логики DirectShow для работы с данными, для доступа к ним, предполагается, что будет написан свой фильтр и встроен в цепочку медиатракта.

Поскольку многие предпочитают не связываться с этими сложностями, а также потому что написание фильтра очень часто предполагает необходимость довольно детально разобраться в ряде аспектов, то популярным является следующее решение.

В процессе построения графа в него встраивают фильтр Sample Grabber, у которого настраивают callback `SampleCB` (несмотря на очевидные недостатки в интернетах более популярен альтернативный метод `BufferCB`) так, чтобы он вызывался с каждым проходящим сквозь фильтр кадром. Фильтр можно настроить так, чтобы формат был - RGB. В происходящем callback вызове будет возможность добраться до самого буфера посредством `IMediaSample.GetPointer`.

В интернете есть тонны примеров по ключевым словам: "Sample Grabber", `MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24`, `SampleCB`. Канонического примера по Sample Grabber нет, потому что, видимо, он для такой популярности не предполагался изначально.

На большом StackOverflow также можно найти много вопросов и обсуждений, проясняющих детали, например:

- [IMediaSample returned by Sample Grabber has unexpected buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431790/imediasample-returned-by-sample-grabber-has-unexpected-buffer-size)
- [DirectShow universal media decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556534/868014)